# Find people from location on Facebook

Tags: web-services, facebook

Is there a way to get a list from all users from certain city from Facebook?
Or any other facebook-independent solution would be great.

thanks

Comment: accept some answers. people might be more willing to answer u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this in the Facebook API. You can get the current location and hometowns of all the friends of a specific user. But not all the users in a specific city.